# VS code and connecting to Ethereum mainnet with ether.js and Infura

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, infura

I don't know why it does not run and I get an error.

Network and API was declared and ethers.js library was imported.

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
const network = "homestead";  
const API_KEY = "mykey"; 
const provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider(network, API_KEY);
const blocknumber = away provider.getBlocknumber();
console.log(blocknumber);
```

Comment: What is the error you get? Please add that information to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what specific error you are getting, but assuming you spelled "await" correctly in your original code, the issue could be that you are accessing InfuraProvider with

```
ethers.providers.InfuraProvider
```

That is the way it is in ethers v5, but in v6 the providers are directly under the ethers class.

If you are using v6 try

```
const provider = new ethers.InfuraProvider(network, apikey);
```

Comment: now I get another error for server connection

Comment: Error: server response 401 Unauthorized (request={  }, response={  }, error=null, code=SERVER_ERROR, version=6.6.5)

Comment: I searched for 401 auth related issue.

Comment: at async file:///home/lucky/Desktop/interacting%20with%20smaqrt%20contracts/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/providers/provider-jsonrpc.js:242:40 {
  code: 'SERVER_ERROR',
  request: FetchRequest {},
  response: FetchResponse {},
  error: undefined

Comment: I have fixed it, I got a new API key and it worked. Your answer was perfect to fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

In line 6 I deleted `provider`, so it's now `new.ethers.infuraprovider()`; before, I was using `ethers.providers.InfuraProvider`.

```js
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { InfuraProvider } from "ethers";
const API_KEY = "1c30bd8247e34d948122ec917e222b3f";
const  network = "homestead";
const provider = new ethers.InfuraProvider(network, API_KEY);
const blockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber();
console.log(blockNumber);
```